# Count non-blank cells in Excel column

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a value in this loop based on counting only cells in column M that contain values (text/numeric). Basically all the used cells. Using AutoHotKey COM script

I tried this, but it just hangs up. No errors though

```
CountUsed := FileFrom.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Range("M:M")

loop, % CountUsed
{
send, ^{PgUp}
sleep, 1000
}
```

And this without input reference:

```
loop, % FileFrom.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Range("M:M")
{
send, ^{PgUp}
sleep, 1000
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like VBA.

Comment: this is auto hot key : https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm

Comment: It’s COM component for AutoHotKey

Comment: guess: Filefrom.Sheets(1).Columns(13).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 7)

Comment: I guess COM and VBA are similar. Support is slow in the AHK forums

Comment: What does the 7 value signify in xlCellTypeConstants, 7?

Comment: 7 would stand for the sum of `xlLogical` (4) + `xlNumbers` (1) + `xlTextValues` (2).

Comment: Tried this one too, but got skunked

    CountUsed := 
    FileFrom.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("M:M"))

    loop, % CountUsed
    {
    send, ^{PgUp}
    sleep, 1000
    }

Comment: This one also didn't work:
myRange = Range("M:M")
NumRows = xlApp.Sheets(1).CountA(myRange)

loop, NumRows
{
send, ^{PgUp}
sleep, 1000
}

Comment: What does it show when you try to print the contents of CountUsed by doing `MsgBox, % CountUsed`?